# Sending 4GB list of objects in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I have a server that contains list with some objects.
the list size is beetween 3GB - 4GB, what make it immposible to used the max message size which is 2147483647 (2.14 GB).

There is way to send this size of list in one transport ?

Or maybe there is a way to seperate the list to small parts and send them multithreading ?

Any ideas will be great !

Comment: Something fishy. Why would you hold a List in memory which is 3GB - 4GB ?

Comment: Yes, batch them up in to multiple calls, but it is a lot of data to be sending down a service, there may be an easier option using ETL. For batching, this article would be a good start: http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/08/batch-or-partition-a-collection-with-linq/

Comment: I think you should read about streaming. However, there are many things to take into consideration. If the WCF is hosted on IIS you also need to add configuration for IIS to allow such a large requests. You can also look into WCF sessions and send all the data in multiple requests, but in the same session. I would start reading about: IIS config for large requests, WCF and ASP.NET streaming, WCF Sessions and then chose the right combination for the specific scenario.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel The data is in the db, i import it in the server side and need to send it to the client.

Comment: Ok, to which client? Are you aware that if the client is 32 bit application you cannot use more than 2GB address space. If you tweak `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` you can use max of 3GB ? Send the data in chunks and use it.

Comment: @Murray Foxcroft I can do the batch with no problem, but how i handle the wcf sending is my lroblem.

Comment: Your WCF service needs to take a parameter for the batch number. Consider two methods. One that returns the number of batches: int GetBatchCount, and another that returns a batch: List<myData> GetBatch(<batch_number>)

Comment: Better yet - DON'T use WCF, you have HTTP and FTP for sending large files. That's actually a best practice Silverlight applications, especially for cases like displaying large reports, exporting files etc.

Comment: @OrCohen what is the real problem you are trying to solve? Are you trying to send a report or Excel file to the client? Are you trying to display 4GB of data to a grid? Are you trying to export the data somewhere? Until now you've described issues with what you thought was the solution.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos i have a db table with objects each object hold files that belong to him. I take all the objects from db and insert them to a list. How do i send this list to client ?

Comment: Maybe break the problem in to two, Why don't you expose the metadata of the files through a WCF services that returns an address for each file. Use HTTP or additional WCF services to download each file.

Comment: Its complicated. I need the objects with the files on them as is. I think i will use batching, i just try to find the best and fastest way to send them to the client

Comment: Cool. Good luck. Look at compression over multi-threading for performance but consider both. Make sure your transport is lightweight - json, BSON or nettcpbinding.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will check those options.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, batch them up in to multiple calls, but it is a lot of data to be sending down a service, there may be an easier option using ETL.

For batching, this article would be a good start: http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/08/batch-or-partition-a-collection-with-linq/  If you create a query for the number of batches, then you can pull them down in parallel.

If you are on a local LAN, then network saturation may not give you the performance you expect from pulling batches down in parallel. Look in to protobuf from Google or other ways to implement compression to gain performance.

Comment: Better yet - use HTTP or FTP to download the entire blob, using the native streaming and restart support of the protocols. ETL can generate the blob (report, file or whatever it is).

Comment: HTTP and FTP have some advantages and disadvantages. They will handle large files very well, but support for retries may requires a re-send of the entire payload or implementing resume logic. They also have limited out of the box support for reconstructing the data on the other end. Compared to WCF, they provide the address and binding, but not the contract.

Comment: I liked the batch way, still try to find a fast way to send all the parts to the client.maybe there is better way then send the part wait till the client handle it and then ask for more.